# Registration failed error due to password field?

Tags: php, json, afnetworking

My app is receiving a `registration failed` error when attempting to sign up with a username and password. These are the functions being used.

index.php (receives a `registration failed` alert when trying to sign up with any username or password)

```
// the functions you call inside the switch are found in the api.php file
switch ($_POST['command']) {
case "login":
    login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
    break;

case "register":
    register($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
    break;
```

api.php

```
// register API
function register($user, $pass) {

//check if username exists in the database (inside the "login" table)
$login = query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE username='%s' limit 1", $user);

if (count($login['result'])>0) {

    //the username exists, return error to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Username already exists');
}

//try to insert a new row in the "login" table with the given username and password
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);

if (!$result['error']) {
    //registration is susccessfull, try to also directly login the new user
    login($user, $pass);
} else {
    //for some database reason the registration is unsuccessful
    errorJson('Registration failed');
}

}

//login API
function login($user, $pass) {

// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);

if (count($result['result'])>0) {
    // a row was found in the database for username/pass combination
    // save a simple flag in the user session, so the server remembers that the user is authorized
    $_SESSION['IdUser'] = $result['result'][0]['IdUser'];

    // print out the JSON of the user data to the iPhone app; it looks like this:
    // {IdUser:1, username: "Name"}
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    // no matching username/password was found in the login table
    errorJson('Authorization failed');
}

}
```

The weird thing is the registration and login processes work when the password paramater in `index.php` is changed to any random string like this `register($_POST['username'], $_POST['_Any_Random_String']);`
 The only thing is the password isn't inserted into the database and one can login with the username selected and any made up password.

```
case "login":
//authenticates user but password isn't uploaded
    login($_POST['username'], $_POST['_Any_Random_String']); 
    break;

 //authenticates user but password isn't uploaded
case "register":
    register($_POST['username'], $_POST['_Any_Random_String']); 
    break;
```

***Edit*** The above code allows user `joey` to register and login with a username `joey` and any password entered. If joey signs up with password `1234` he will also be able to login with the password `12345678` or any password when logging in even though he signed up with password `1234`. Also, the password `1234` or any input in the password field isn't stored into the database.

How can the app post the password via `$_POST['password']` as needed?

***Update***

Charles Proxy Output

```
command register
username    fxjzfnfx 
password    ®0i!0öºk}p«)ÛèGS¡{

{
"error": "Registration failed"
}
```

Comment: You obviously don't hash the passwords before storing them in the database and that's a very bad practice. Apart that, I dont really understand what your issue is. You should provide better detail on what works and what not.

Comment: That seemed weird to be too but the app came that way. I edited the question with a use case. Basically when I try to register with `register($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); ` it doesn't work. But when the password parameter is set to an empty string it works but no password is stored in the database.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does that `query` function do? Does it check for any errors? What about SQL injection - have you thought about securing your code against it?

Comment: I've checked the error logs to see what it says. The query is supposed to insert a new row in the "login" table with the given username and password. It does check for an error via `} else {
  //for some database reason the registration is unsuccessful
  errorJson('Registration failed');
 }`. I will secure the code after the login works successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
//try to insert a new row in the "login" table with the given username and password
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);
```

to

```
//try to insert a new row in the "login" table with the given username and password
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES(" . $user . "," . $pass . ")");
```

And replace this

```
// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND pass='%s' limit 1", $user, $pass);
```

to

```
// try to match a row in the "login" table for the given username and password
$result = query("SELECT IdUser, username FROM login WHERE username=". $user . " AND  pass=" . $pass ." limit 1");
```

Comment: I will update the question with results from the error log. It's weird because it doesn't show anything in the error log at all. The only thing that shows the error is the alert within the app that says `registration failed`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO login(username, pass) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);
```

Here check your last query what is executing. Are you getting the both values or not. It is also possible that some other field in your table is required.

Comment: Yep. Only the username is being posted to the database. I'll check Charles proxy and see what it says and update the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? How does this solve the problem?